# Delete EBS Snapshot From Shell Script with Name and Date FIlter

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2

Hi I want to delete EBS snapshot which is older then 30 days and want to filter out with pharse of it's name. Let's say the name contain word 'Manish'.
The name can be like that 'Manish-Ebs-snapshot' or EBS-Manish-snapshot or EBS-ManishFinal-Snapshot' like that.
I found out one command but it's collecting all the snapshot not a particular group of snapshot.

```
    snapshots_to_delete=$(aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids xxxxxxxxxxxx --query 'Snapshots[?StartTime<=`2020-08-23`].SnapshotId' --output text)
    echo "List of snapshots to delete: $snapshots_to_delete"
    for snap in $snapshots_to_delete; do
      aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id $snap
    done
```

can anyone help me with this above script how I can add name filter as well.

The field I want:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter by description using `*Manish*`:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids xxxxxxxxx --filter Name=description,Values=*Manish* --query 'Snapshots[?StartTime<=`2020-08-23`].SnapshotId'
```

And by **tag** `Name`:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids xxxxxxxx --filter Name=tag:Name,Values=*Manish* --query 'Snapshots[?StartTime<=`2020-08-23`].SnapshotId'
```

Comment: Thanks @marcin , but I was not looking for description, we are looking for Name filter not description filter. Even there is a syntax error in your command description needs to be in small characters

Comment: @ManishParida Thanks, I changed to `description`. Not sure what do you mean by "name". There is no such filed in [describe-snapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-snapshots.html#output). Can you indicate which field you mean specifically?

Comment: Added a picture for your reference @Marcin

Comment: @ManishParida Answer updated. The `Name` in this case is tag. So you have to filter by tag value.